# Bioisosteric replacement using SMARTS (KNIME and RDKit)

Tags: knime, chemistry, rdkit

I am trying to create a KNIME workflow that would accept a list of compounds and carry out **bioisosteric replacements** (we will use the following *example* here: *carboxylic acid to tetrazole*) automatically.

> NOTE: I am using the following workflow as inspiration : [RDKit-bioisosteres (myexperiment.org)](https://www.myexperiment.org/workflows/2683.html). This uses a text file as SMARTS input. **I cannot seem to replicate the SMARTS format used here.**

For this, I plan to use the [Rdkit One Component Reaction](https://nodepit.com/node/org.rdkit.knime.nodes.onecomponentreaction2.RDKitOneComponentReactionNodeFactory) node which uses a set of compounds to carry out the reaction on as input and a SMARTS string that defines the reaction.

**My issue is the generation of a working SMARTS string describing the reaction.**

I would like to input two SDF files (or another format, not particularly attached to SDF): one with the group to replace (*carboxylic acid*) and one with the list of possible bioisosteric replacements (*tetrazole*). I would then combine these two in KNIME and generate a SMARTS string for the reaction to then be used in the *Rdkit One Component Reaction* node.

> NOTE: The input SDF files have the structures written with an
> attachment point (*COOH for the carboxylic acid for example) which
> defines where the group to replace is attached. I suspect this is the
> cause of many of the issues I am experiencing.

So far, I can easily generate the reactions in RXN format using the [Reaction Builder node](https://nodepit.com/node/com.epam.indigo.knime.rbuilder.IndigoReactionBuilderNodeFactory) from the Indigo node package. However, converting this reaction into a SMARTS string that is accepted by the [Rdkit One Component Reaction](https://nodepit.com/node/org.rdkit.knime.nodes.onecomponentreaction2.RDKitOneComponentReactionNodeFactory) node has proven tricky.

What I have tried so far:

1. Converting RXN to SMARTS ([Molecule Type Cast](https://nodepit.com/node/org.knime.chem.base.node.converter.parser.MolParserNodeFactory) node) : gives the following error code : `scanner: BufferScanner::read() error`
2. Converting the Source and Target molecules into SMARTS (*Molecule Type Cast* node) : gives the following error code : `SMILES loader: unrecognised lowercase symbol: y`

   - showing this as a string in KNIME shows that the conversion is not carried out and the string is of SDF format : `*filename*.sdf 0 0 0 0  0 0    0 V3000M V30 BEGIN` etc.
3. Converting the Source and Target molecules into RDkit first ([RDkit from Molecule](https://nodepit.com/node/org.rdkit.knime.nodes.molecule2rdkit.Molecule2RDKitConverterNodeFactory) node) then from RDkit into SMARTS ([RDkit to Molecule](https://nodepit.com/node/org.rdkit.knime.nodes.rdkit2molecule.RDKit2MoleculeConverterNodeFactory) node, SMARTS option). This outputs the following SMARTS strings:

   - Carboxylic acid : `[#6](-[#8])=[#8]`
   - Tetrazole : `[#6]1:[#7H]:[#7]:[#7]:[#7]:1`

This is as close as I've managed to get. I can then join these two smarts strings with `>>` in between (output: `[#6](-[#8])=[#8]>>[#6]1:[#7H]:[#7]:[#7]:[#7]:1`) to create a SMARTS reaction string but this is not accepted as an input for the Rdkit One Component Reaction node.

> Error message in KNIME console :
> ERROR RDKit One Component Reaction 0:40       Creation of Reaction from SMARTS value failed: null
> WARN  RDKit One Component Reaction 0:40       Invalid Reaction SMARTS: missing

Note that the SMARTS strings that this last option (3.) generates are very different than the ones used in the [myexperiments.org example](https://www.myexperiment.org/workflows/2683.html) (`[*:1][C:2]([OH])=O>>[*:1][C:2]1=NNN=N1`). I also seem to have lost the attachment point information through these conversions which are likely to cause issues in the rest of the workflow.

**Therefore I am looking for a way to generate the SMARTS strings used in the myexperiments.org example on my own sets of substituents.** Obviously doing this by hand is not an option. I would also like this workflow to use only the open-source nodes available in KNIME and not proprietary nodes (Schrodinger etc.).

Hopefully, someone can help me out with this. If you need my current workflow I am happy to upload that with the source files if required.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Stay safe and healthy!

-Antoine

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is template generation, which has been a consistent field of work in reaction prediction and/or retrosynthesis in cheminformatics for a long time.
I'm not particularly familiar with KNIME myself, though I know RDKit extensively: Your last option (3) is closest to what I'd consider a usable workflow. The way I would do this:

1. Load the substitution pair molecules from SDF into RDKit mol objects.
2. Export these RDKit mol objects as SMARTS strings `rdkit.Chem.MolToSmarts()`.
3. Concatenate these strings into the form `before_substructure>>after_substructure` to generate a reaction SMARTS string.
4. Load this SMARTS string into a reaction object `rxn = rdkit.Chem.AllChem.ReactionFromSmarts()`
5. Use the `rxn.RunReactants()` [method](https://www.rdkit.org/docs/RDKit_Book.html#reaction-smarts) to generate your bioisosterically substituted products.

The error you quote for the RDKit One Component Reaction node input cuts off just before the important information, unfortunately. Running `rdkit.Chem.AllChem.ReactionFromSmarts("[#6](-[#8])=[#8]>>[#6]1:[#7H]:[#7]:[#7]:[#7]:1")` produces no errors for me locally, which leads me to believe this is specific to the KNIME node functionality.

Note, that the difference between `[#6](-[#8])=[#8]` and `[*:1][C:2]([OH])=O` is relatively minimal: The former represents a `O-C=O` substructure, the latter represents a `~COOH` group. Within the square brackets of the latter, the `:num` refers to an optional 'atom map' number, which allows a one-to-one mapping of reactant and product atoms. For example, `[C:1][C:3].[C:2][C:4]>>[C:1][C:3][C:4][C:2]` allows you to track which carbon is which during a reaction, for situations where it may matter. The token `[*:1]` means "any atom" and is equivalent to a [wavey line](https://www.chem.ucla.edu/%7Eharding/IGOC/W/wavy_line.html) in organic chemistry (and it is mapped to #1).
There are only two situations I can think of where `[#6](-[#8])=[#8]` and `[*:1][C:2]([OH])=O` might differ:

- You have methanoic acid as a potential input for substitution (former will match, latter *might* not - I can't remember how implicit hydrogens are treated in this situation)
- Inputs are over/under protonated. (`COO-` != `COOH`)

Converting these reaction SMARTS to RDKit reaction objects and running them on input molecule objects should potentially create a number of substituted products. Note: Typically, in extensive projects, there will be some SMARTS templates that require some degree of manual intervention - indicating attachment points, specifying explicit hydrogens, etc. If you need any help or have any questions don't hesitate to drop a comment and I'll do my best to help with specifics.